# Getting accurate timings in logs for streaming responses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Using Rails 3.2.14. I'm streaming a controller action response, as follows.

```
def my_controller_action
    stream = StreamingClass.new(*args) #responds to each
    response.sending_file= true
    headers.merge!(
      'Content-Disposition'       => 'inline',
      'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary',
      'Cache-Control'             => 'no-cache'
       )
       self.status = 200
    self.content_type= 'application/json'
    self.response_body = stream
end
```

The streaming works just fine, but the problem is that the controller action returns before the streaming is completed (i.e. before each is called on the 'stream' object). It basically returns immediately after assigning the 'stream' object to self.response_body.

I'm using the lograge gem to tidy up our logging. Lograge basically subscribes to the 'process_action.action_controller' notifications. It is logging the timings (i.e. duration, db_runtime, etc...) based on the actual controller return time, without tracking any time spent on the stream object code.

The heavy lifting occurs in a StreamingClass method, but I'm completely missing this info from the logs. Is there some way to include the streaming response timings in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into this same issue also. It seems to me that the only way to tell when the streaming is complete is to wrap the `response_body` in a proxy object whose `close` method includes additional logic which records the stats you need. You could probably use something like this:

```
class BodyProxy
  def initialize(body)
    @body = body
  end

  def each(&block)
    @body.each(&block)
  end

  def close
    @body.close if @body.respond_to?(:close)
    # Your code here. Probably something involving `Time.now`
  end
end
```

This works because the [Rack specification](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/SPEC.html) requires that `close` be called on the body "after iteration".

I'm unfamiliar with Lograge, so I don't know how you would send this information to that gem, but this should be enough to get you started.